# 0 Rows returned on a string search

Tags: mysql, sql

Query =

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE 'key' = 'exchange_rate'
```

Table structure =

```
key varchar(500)    latin1_swedish_ci   
value   text    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Table content

```
Key           | Value
exchange_rate | 25
```

Program

```
phpMyAdmin 4.0.4 Mysql
```

Result

```
0 Rows returned
```

Do you know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE `key` = 'exchange_rate'
```

instead of :

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE 'key' = 'exchange_rate'
```

Comment: `key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Qoutes are used to show varchar values not column name

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE `key` = 'exchange_rate'
```